# parse HTML javascript to JAVA using selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the value of h1 as a string using selenium.

Here is the HTML javascript-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {    
        var $windowHeight = $(window).height() -12;
        $("#top").height($windowHeight);
        $('h1').css({
                'margin-top' : (($windowHeight) - $('h1').outerHeight())/2,
                'margin-bottom' : (($windowHeight) - $('h1').outerHeight())/2,
                'opacity' : '1.0',
                'filter' : 'alpha(opacity = 100)',
        });

        $("#container").click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ 
                scrollTop: $windowHeight + 50
            }, 1500);
        })

    });
    $(window).on("debouncedresize", function( event ) {
        var $windowHeight = $(window).height() -12;
        $("#top").height($windowHeight);
        $('h1').css({
                'margin-top' : (($windowHeight) - $('h1').outerHeight())/2,
                'margin-bottom' : (($windowHeight) - $('h1').outerHeight())/2
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is what I've written in JAVA-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    driver.get("view-source:http://websitename.com/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    JavascriptExecutor js = null;
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    }
    js.executeScript("h1");
```

Not sure if I should be using JavascriptExecutor in the first place. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Hi AnV, and welcome to stackoverflow. We need a bit more information before we can answer your question - what exactly are you trying to get, when you say 'the value of h1'? Do you want the user-visible text in the h1 heading, or the full html of the h1 tag, or the css, or something else?

Comment: Hi vincebowdren, thanks. Yes, I'm trying to get the user-visible text in the h1 heading. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

h1 is a tag on the page. Why do you try accessing it using JavascriptExecutor?
If you want to get text of the header h1 simply use such code

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.css("h1")).getText();
```

If you want to get an attribute of the tag use this code instead

```
String attr= driver.findElement(By.css("h1")).getAttribute(<attr-name>);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Yes, I want to get the text of the header h1. After running
String text = driver.findElement(By.css("h1")).getText();

I'm getting this error- 
The method css(String) is undefined for the type By

Comment: Replaced css by cssSelector. The error is gone but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It works now! I was supposed to get the source of the page by using driver.getPageSource(); Not by driver.get("view-source:websitename.com/"). Stupid me. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Why are you getting the entire source of the page at all? It really is more efficient to use a call like `getText()` or get `Attribute()` to find the precise information you want.

Comment: Do I not have to use driver.get() at all? Can you maybe give me an example?

Comment: The answer posted by user2525437 has examples of what I mean.